# how to align an element inside a block of DockLayoutPanel in GWT/ UiBinder?

Tags: gwt, uibinder

```
<g:DockLayoutPanel unit='PX' ui:field="dock1">
   <g:north size='40'>     
      <g:DockLayoutPanel unit='PX' ui:field="dock2">......</g:DockLayoutPanel>
   </g:north>
</g:DockLayoutPanel>
```

How to align the `dock2` in `g:north` of `dock1` to CENTER & to MIDDLE?

Answer (score 0):

i knew the answer sinc DockLayout fulls up the whole area, so we can't make it to the middle, therefore instead of trying to align the whole `dock2` in `g:north`, i just need o align the elements inside `dock2`, this time it works ok.